Not able to get my env variable in lib folder in next js 14 using app router
I am using next js 14 app router and not using the src directory... The problem I am facing is that my .env file is in root directory and I want to get access to my env variables in lib folder this lib folder is also in the root directory and inside the lib folder I have the file azure-blob.ts this is the code in the file
"use server";

import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";

async function uploadToAzureBlobStorage(file: any) {
  console.log("Function is invoking");
  try {
    const azure_string =
      process.env.CONNECTION_STRING;
    console.log("Azure Storage connection string:", azure_string);

    if (!azure_string) {
      throw new Error("Azure Storage connection string is not set");
    }

    const containerName = process.env.CONTAINER_NAME;
    console.log("Container name:", containerName);
    if (!containerName) {
      throw new Error("Azure Blob container name is not set");
    }

    const blobServiceClient =
      BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(azure_string);
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

    const file_key =
      "uploads/" + Date.now().toString() + file.name.replace(/ /g, "-");
    console.log("File key for upload:", file_key);

    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(file_key);
    await blockBlobClient.uploadBrowserData(file);
    console.log("Upload successful:", file_key);

    return {
      file_key,
      file_name: file.name,
    };
  } catch (error:any) {
    console.error("Error object:", error);
    console.error("Error uploading to Azure Blob Storage:", error.message || "Unknown error");
    throw error;
}
}

export default uploadToAzureBlobStorage;

I tried adding dotenv in this file and set multiple paths to it but nothing is working whenever this function is invoking the error is that Connection string is undefiend

try changing the file name to .env.local, also check the official NextJS Docs for Environment Variables

There's a few ways to skin this cat.
blob-config.ts
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config({ path: '../yourenvfile.env' });

export const azureConfig = {
  CONNECTION_STRING: process.env.CONNECTION_STRING || '',
  CONTAINER_NAME: process.env.CONTAINER_NAME || '',
};

azure-blob.ts
import { azureConfig } from 'blob-config';

async function uploadToAzureBlobStorage(file: any) {
  const azure_string = azureConfig.CONNECTION_STRING;
  const containerName = azureConfig.CONTAINER_NAME;
  // Rest of the function...
}


I have already implemented this but its still not working the issue lies somewhere in the path but in next js 14 .env.local works everywhere right ?

@RohanAdnan No, only from the root directory.

@RohanAdnan Try ./lib/yourconfigname.env.local instead of ../yourenvfile.env. Swap the name with whatever yours is. And yes, the single . is intentional. If it works I'll update my answer.
